# I want to a get Result in SQL Server Using UNION and Group ignore 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

Here is my code

```sql
DECLARE @Fromdate date = '2021-06-5';
DECLARE @Todate date = '2021-06-5';
DECLARE @till01 varchar(200) = 'ST-LO-01';
DECLARE @till02 varchar(200) = 'ST-LO-02';
DECLARE @till03 varchar(200) = 'ST-LO-03';
DECLARE @till04 varchar(200) = 'ST-LO-04';
DECLARE @till05 varchar(200) = 'ST-LO-05';
DECLARE @till06 varchar(200) = 'ST-LO-06';

SELECT Srt.TRANSDATE,
       Srt.TERMINAL AS TILL,
       ISNULL(COUNT(Srt.TRANSACTIONID), 0) AS Total_Inv,
       0 AS Empty_Info
FROM RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE Srt
    LEFT JOIN RetailTransactionInfoCodeTrans Cinf ON Cinf.TRANSACTIONID = Srt.TRANSACTIONID
WHERE Srt.TRANSDATE >= @Fromdate
  AND Srt.TRANSDATE <= @Todate
  AND Srt.TYPE = 2
  AND Srt.TERMINAL IN (@till01, @till02, @till03, @till04)
GROUP BY Srt.TRANSDATE,
         Srt.TERMINAL
UNION
SELECT Srt.TRANSDATE,
       Srt.TERMINAL AS TILL,
       0 AS TOTAL,
       ISNULL(COUNT(Srt.TRANSACTIONID), 0) AS EMPTY
FROM RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE Srt
    LEFT JOIN RetailTransactionInfoCodeTrans Cinf ON Cinf.TRANSACTIONID = Srt.TRANSACTIONID
WHERE Srt.TRANSDATE >= @Fromdate
  AND Srt.TRANSDATE <= @Todate
  AND Srt.TYPE = 2
  AND Srt.TERMINAL IN (@till01, @till02, @till03, @till04)
  AND Cinf.information IS NULL
GROUP BY Srt.TERMINAL,
         Srt.TRANSDATE
ORDER BY Srt.TRANSDATE,
         Srt.TERMINAL,
         Empty_Info ASC;
```

Result is:

| TRANSDATE | TILL | Total_Inv | Empty_Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-01 | 197 | 0 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-01 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-02 | 175 | 0 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-02 | 0 | 4 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-03 | 240 | 0 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-03 | 0 | 9 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-04 | 207 | 0 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-04 | 0 | 9 |

I want this result:

| TRANSDATE | TILL | Total_Inv | Empty_Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-01 | 197 | 2 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-02 | 175 | 4 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-03 | 240 | 9 |
| 2021-06-05 | ST-LO-04 | 207 | 9 |

Comment: @Larnu i am using also Union and Union All, but Result are sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you should just be using some conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Srt.TRANSDATE,
       Srt.TERMINAL AS TILL,
       COUNT(Srt.TRANSACTIONID) AS Total_Inv, --Count can return 0 already, no need for the ISNULL
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Cinf.information  IS NULL THEN Srt.TRANSACTIONID END) AS Empty_Info
FROM RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE Srt
    LEFT JOIN RetailTransactionInfoCodeTrans Cinf ON Cinf.TRANSACTIONID = Srt.TRANSACTIONID
WHERE Srt.TRANSDATE >= @Fromdate
  AND Srt.TRANSDATE <= @Todate
  AND Srt.TYPE = 2
  AND Srt.TERMINAL IN (@till01, @till02, @till03, @till04)
GROUP BY Srt.TRANSDATE,
         Srt.TERMINAL;
```